# Query result Records are taking long time

Tags: java, oracle, collections

I have a scenario where a Bulk number of records, **not less than 8000**, needs to be fetched from DB at a time and then setting them all in a 'resultList' (an ArrayList object) before rendering the result jsp page. There is a parent-child relationship in the resultSet (where almost 3000 are parent records and rest are children) and I did iterating over the parent using **one for loop**, and again iterating over the child records using ***another for loop*** to set in the arraylist.

But it is taking minimum of **30 mins** to iterate over the 2 for loops!
While my db query fetch takes just **1.5 min** to get all records from DB. I used oracle in db connection.

My question is, **How can I decrease the turnaround time of my code? How can I minimize the looping time? Is there any other possibilities to get the bulk records?** please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, getting that amount of records to the client is kind of bad design - avoid it if possible. If you are 100% sure you have to perform that huge fetch - let the server do the job. That is redesign your process into maybe two queries to avoid nested loops on client.

Comment: I need to perform the Huge fetch, that is for sure (condition is such that). 

If I separate the bulk records into 2 separate queries and then iterate over 2 different resultSets twice (2 for loops), will it minimize the Query result records' overall time?

Comment: It is hard to help you given the level of details you have provided. Just the general ideas - make the server do the job as much as possible. Avoid client-side iterations as much as possible. Experiment with smaller (test) loads to determine which exactly line of client code is the slowest.

Comment: Okay, I understand your point. Let me check with your suggestion. Thanks for providing an idea.